# How to convert back the model output for single input to one of the prediction classes?

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, neural-network, label-encoding

I've been using LabelEncoder for categorical output

```
from keras.utils import np_utils
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
label = LabelEncoder()
y_train = np_utils.to_categorical(label.fit_transform(y_train))
y_test = np_utils.to_categorical(label.fit_transform(y_test))
```

and there are 4 classes in output,
after encoding, the labels look like this
[image: encoded labels]

And model looks like  this:

```
model0 = Sequential()
model0.add(Conv1D(32, kernel_size=(3), input_shape=input_shape))
model0.add(Conv1D(64, kernel_size=(3)))
model0.add(Conv1D(128, kernel_size=(3)))
model0.add(Conv1D(64, kernel_size=(3)))
model0.add(Conv1D(32, kernel_size=(3)))
model0.add(Flatten())
model0.add(Dense(128, activation='relu'))
model0.add(Dense(12, activation='relu'))
model0.add(Dense(4, activation='softmax'))

model0.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
```

After training, while predicting how to get the output as one of the classes? I tried using:

```
model0.predict_classes(feature.reshape(1,num_features,1))
array([3], dtype=int64)
```

How can I know to which class the output belongs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution: we can use the `inverse_transform()` method in the `LabelEncoder` class,

The code goes like this:

```
result = model0.predict_classes(feature.reshape(1,num_features,1))
print(label.inverse_transform(result))
```

Comment: Please accept your own answer - nothing wrong with that. It is not a testimony to your failure but rather an encouragement that you are starting to learn (and master) the art of debugging and are able to help yourself. It is something that is a highly prized skill especially in Real-life situations.....

Comment: Site doesn't allow me to accept my own answer before 48 hours , So I've to wait for 18 hours more to accept this answer : )